# Primary Contact folder on Opportunities reports

Tags: force.com, reporting, opportunity, opportunitycontactrole

On the standard opportunities report there is a folder called Primary Contact. Where is that information coming from? Is it the primary contact on the Contact Role associated with the Opp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is the Primary Contact Role.  When you select a New Contact Role from the Opportunity Page layout, there's a radio box which lets you designate the Primary Contact.

[image: primary contact]